# General Directory (e.g. not user specific)

Tags: directory, generalization

I'm trying to write an addon for a program that will hopefully be released online. In it, I need to access the user files. How do I do this in a general way? If my directory is `/Users/MYNAME/Library/Application Support/...`, how do I write this in a general way so that everyone who uses my addon can use it regardless of if their name is the same as mine? Also, what would be the PC equivalent?

Comment: Any answer would depend, in part, on what language you are using.  And what operating system.

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm using python and I'm on a mac, though I'd like for it to be accessible on PC as well. My plan is to do a check at the start to determine which computer the user is using, then set the directory accordingly.